# Loop to create multiple reports dependent on a date

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I need to create multiple reports at once taking into consideration the date column.

For example:

```
INVOICE     COMMENT       DATE
------------------------------------
1111        example1      14/04/2018
2222        example2      14/04/2018
3333        example3      15/04/2018
4444        example4      18/04/2018
```

For day 14/04/2018 I would need to generate two PDF with this data:

- 1111-example1-14/04/2018
- 2222-example2-14/04/2018

So basically one for each row with today's date. On 15/04/2018 only one report would be created.

I need SSRS "to loop" between dates and creating a PDF file for each one. Obviously the query would be larger, but this is just and example.

Is this even possible with SSRS or maybe there are other ways to do it?

Comment: I don't know any way to create a separate PDF for each, but it's possible to create one PDF with each report on its own page.

Comment: Do you mean a PDF with 2+ pages, with a report in each page? That would not work for me, we need a separate file for each one.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a data-driven subscription. You would need to write a small query that returns all the parameter values you want to use. When it runs, it will create a copy of the report for each value you specify. You can have the resulting PDF emailed or stored in a directory.

Comment: We are currently using Standard edition, so Data-driven subscription is not an option I think...

Comment: The data-driven subscription interface is a user-friendly way of scheduling SQL Server jobs to perform this work. You could look into setting those up manually. That's the only decent alternative I'm aware of.